# Windows 10 Dialog Box titlebar behavior

Tags: c, winapi, dialog, windows-10, titlebar

How do I get the dialog box titlebars to be thick in my applications like the dialog boxes in Windows 10.  I have noticed a behavior where if the minimum Windows version is set to 6.0 or higher in the linker options it will cause the titlebars to be thick.
I have `<supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>` in my application manifest yet if I set the minimum Windows version in the EXE file with the linker to 5.01 (for XP compatibility) the titlebars will be thinner.

The application is written in a mix of C and C++ and uses plain Windows API.

Is there any way to get titlebars in dialog boxes to use the non-backwards-compatible behavior without dropping XP support for my application?

[image: Example of the problem]

Comment: Do you want an answer or not? Your bounty message states that you want a specific answer. What if that is not the answer to the question? Are you interested in getting the right answer, or are you only going to accept the answer that you want to hear?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I am pretty much convinced it is an internal behavior of the window manager, and as such I am now distributing two versions of my application:  An XP-compatible version compiled in Visual Studio 2010 and a Vista+ compatible version compiled in Visual Studio 2017, which also requires a SSE2-capable processor to run.

Answer (score -3):

What you can do is set your dialog box as borderless and draw your own title bar and close button. That would guarantee portability amongst all platforms, as drawing would then be entirely specified by your code, rather than allowed to the discretion of the operating system API.

Comment: This should go without saying, but when the goal is to get the *native behavior*, completely disabling said native behavior and instead doing it all yourself — i.e. guaranteeing non-nativeness — not only doesn't accomplish the goal, but goes *contrary* to it.